# Error while passing file Object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have created a file object and passing to a method but it gives me this error -

> this.file = File.fromPath(filePath);

This is how, I pass to a method -

```
setTimeout(() => this.recognizeTextOnMobile(this.file), 1000);
```

But I see the below error -

> /node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system").File' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'File'. Argument of type
> 'import("node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system").File'
> is not assignable to parameter of type 'File'.   Type 'File' is
> missing the following properties from type 'File': type, slice.

Or if I do like the below -

```
const file : File = fs.File.fromPath(path);
```

I still see this error -

> Type 'File' is missing the following properties from type 'File':
> type, slice.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you by chance declare `this.file` like `file: File` but not `import {File} from 'tns-core-modules/file-system';`? There's a global type named `File` in many environments that describes part of the browser's upload API and it could be in scope.

Comment: Well, without more information, your function definitions and imports, there's not much to go on then.

Comment: Sure. But this isn't a good question and you should learn how to write one by providing the relevant code. I can't tell what you are importing from what you've shown so consider improving the question.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean but you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).